# How do I update the state to force a rerender if my props change in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My parent component sends a prop called `array` and if this prop changes, I want the child component to re-render with the new prop.

So here is what I added in my child component:

```
  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (!isEqual(prevProps.array, this.props.array)) {
      this.setState({array: this.props.array});
    }
  };
```

It seems to be working, although I'm wondering if I thought too much and there's an easier way. Someone suggested `If they're equal, couldn't you update the state with the new array anyway?` earlier but I wasn't quite sure what that meant and haven't been able to get clarity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In React, the `Child` component should render in case there is a change in its props, so this code in `componentDidUpdate` is not necessary as the component will re-render on its own. 
And if you also want to update a state then this piece of code is fine in that case. Although it's recommended to not have the `props` and `state` with the same name.

Comment: understood. yea even though it re-renders my state doesn't update unless I have this piece of code. that's why I was wondering if what I have is correct

Comment: Yeah, that is the correct approach to do that. You can also use the equality operator directly(but that's not an issue). Btw I wondering why are you using a `state` element when you already have a `prop` for the same that variable.

Comment: in my UI the state is modified based on user input, wheres prop stays immutable and provided by the parent component. But actually, now I'm thinking do I even need to check if the previous props and new props are not equal? My end goal was to update the state with the new prop.... so can I just remove this line if (!isEqual(prevProps.array, this.props.array)) and always set it? Is it good practice to ignore prevProp and prevState in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: It is a good practice to keep a check on the `prevProps` in the `componentDidMount` otherwise even when there is not any change in the props then also the whole `lifecycle method` will get executed which may cause problems.

Comment: So, you should keep the condition as it is.